# Case sensitive in ElasticSearch for string field

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

How should I modify my query to get application with specified name, but letter case will be skipped. Result will contain: 'MYAPPLICATION', "myAppliCATion" etc

Version: 6.2.2

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "application": "MyApplication"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if the `application` field is a `text` field (i.e. analyzed)  it should work.

Comment: This might be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54237171/two-kinds-of-search-on-a-field/54237577#54237577